# exact histogram of an array

Tags: python, numpy

How to get occurrence counts for for the elements of a float array?. 
If the array is 
[-1,2,3,-1,3,4,4,4,4,4],
the result should be 
[2,1,2,5],
not necessarily in that order, and the mapping from counts to the elements that are counted is not needed, only counts matter.

numpy.histogram would do something similar, but it must use bins, which requires precomputing bin-size to separate the elements and can also   create unnecessarily many empty bins.

This can also be done manually with hashing or sorting, but 
it seems there should be a fast, one-shot way without python-level loops.

Thanks!

Edit:

I tried the solutions suggested at the time of writing and thought I'd share the results as they are somewhat unexpected. 
What I did not mention originally is that the flow works with rather small lists, but the operation is invoked millions of times, which is somewhat a cornercase.

The test and its printout are below. histogramize1 is my original function whose performance I wanted to improve. It is by x2 faster then the second fastest, and it would be interesting to know why.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from timeit import timeit


def histogramize1(X):
    cnts = {}
    for x in X:
        if x in cnts:
            cnts[x] += 1
        else:
            cnts[x] = 1
    lst = [ v for k,v in cnts.iteritems() ]

    lX = len(X)
    return [ float(x)/lX for x in lst ]


def histogramize2(X):

    ua,uind= np.unique(X,return_inverse=True)
    lX = len(X)    
    res = [float(x)/lX for x in np.bincount(uind)]

    return res


def histogramize3(X):
    counts = Counter(X)
    lX = len(X)
    res = [float(x)/lX for x in counts.viewvalues()]
    return res

def histogramize4(X):
    lX = len(X)
    return [float(X.count(i))/lX for i in np.unique(X)]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    lst0 = [-1,2,3,-1,3,4,4,4,4,4]
    lst = lst0 + lst0 + lst0 + lst0

    num = 100000
    print timeit("histogramize1(lst)",setup="from __main__ import histogramize1, lst",number=num)
    print timeit("histogramize2(lst)",setup="from __main__ import histogramize2, lst",number=num)
    print timeit("histogramize3(lst)",setup="from __main__ import histogramize3, lst",number=num)
    print timeit("histogramize4(lst)",setup="from __main__ import histogramize4, lst",number=num)
```

This prints:

1.35243415833

10.0806729794

2.89171504974

15.5577590466

Comment: @JonClements - There's one additional wrinkle, though... `bincount` expects non-negative integers.  The OP will need to `numpy.bincount(x - x.min())` or something similar.  `bincount` will also return `0` in place of any elements that are "skipped" (e.g. if the OP's example had 5's in place of the 4's, the returned result would be `[2, 1, 2, 0, 5]`, telling you that there are no 4's.)

Comment: @JoeKington That only occurred to me shortly after posting - hence the removal of my comment - but thanks for taking the time to explain out why `numpy.bincount` isn't immediately as obvious a solution as one first thinks ;)

Comment: This is a dangerous idea... Floating point arithmetic is inherently inexact, and for instance `2./3. == 1. - 1./3.` returns `False` on my system. Unless all your floats have been generated in the exact same way, you cannot count on two values that should be the same actually being so.

Comment: @Jaime `numpy.round`/`numpy.around`/`numpy.round_` work just fine for that.

Comment: @JAB But you have to round your values before you get into counting them, which is something no one seemed to care, happily demonstrating solutions by running them on ints...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Python 2.7+:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter([-1,2,3,-1,3,4,4,4,4,4])
>>> counts.viewvalues() # counts.values() in Python 3+
dict_values([1, 2, 5, 2])
```

http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter (There are implementations for 2.4 and 2.5 if you're stuck with older versions, though.)

And since `Counter` is subclassed from `dict`, you *can* get the values that are counted if you ever need them. `counts.viewitems()` (2.7) or `counts.items()` (3+) will give you an iterable mapping.

Answer (score 4):

If you do want a numpy solution:

```
>>> a=np.array( [-1,2,3,-1,3,4,4,4,4,4])
>>> ua,uind=np.unique(a,return_inverse=True)

#This returns the unique values and indices of those values.
>>> ua
array([-1,  2,  3,  4])
>>> uind
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])

>>> np.bincount(uind)
array([2, 1, 2, 5])
```

This has the additional benefit of showing what count goes with what number.

A bit over twice as fast for small arrays to boot:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

a=np.random.randint(0,100,(500))
alist=a.tolist()

In [27]: %timeit  Counter(alist).viewvalues()
1000 loops, best of 3: 209 us per loop

In [28]: %timeit ua,uind=np.unique(a,return_inverse=True);np.bincount(uind)
10000 loops, best of 3: 85.8 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is the most elegan solution, but you could use this oneliner:

```
import numpy
aa = [-1,2,3,-1,3,4,4,4,4,4]
histogr = [aa.count(i) for i in numpy.unique(aa)]
```

Comment: It is short indeed! However, this would produce quadratic runtime as I believe count is implemented by raw iteration over the array. Could be useful when number of unique elements is known to be small.